# Problem with pdflatex and dviopt

Tags: mactex, ghostscript

I just reinstalled my latex distribution: earlier I used MacTeX Basic with some extensions. Now I am using MacTeX full (comparable to TexLive Full). Since the switch, I suddenly have a different problem. Using `pdfopt` I always get the following errors.

```
   **** Considering object with an invalid number 13 as null.
   **** Considering object with an invalid number 14 as null.
   **** Considering object with an invalid number 13 as null.
   **** Considering object with an invalid number 14 as null.
```

A minimal example is

```
\documentclass{report}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

Then

```
pdflatex file
```

and

```
pdfopt file.pdf newfile.pdf
```

the errors show up.

Prior to reinstalling this problem did not occur.

Manual inspection does not show an error, but I am concerned as I am batch-producing the files, so manual inspection does not look like a good approach

System: MacTeX 2012, full. MacBook 2010 15", Mountain Lion.

Comment: Ok, seems I solved my own problem. So this can be closed. 
The full distribution of MacTex 2012 contains ghostscript 9.05 which has a broken pdfopt (documented in the repository of ghostscript). It seems the basic version contains the 9.06, which is fine. 
So, I downloaded the ghostscript 9.06 version from http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/ and installed it over.. - now problems are gone.